# Notions of tangent plane at function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

For a differentiable function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ the equation of the tangent plane at $x_0$ is $0 = f'(x_0) x - y$. But some functions not differentiable like $\sqrt x$ at $x_0 = 0$ still have a tangent plane there. So my question is there a more general way to obtain a tangent plane for not neccessarily differentiable functions, and is there a way to surely tell if a function has a tangent plane, for example $\sqrt x$ at $x_0 = 0$ has one, but
$$
 f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} -x & x < 0 \\
                                  x+1 & x \ge 0 \end{array}\right.
$$
has none at $x_0 = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean *tangent line* rather than "tangent plane". You can view the graph of $y=\sqrt{x}$ in the $x,y$ plane as part of the graph of $x=y^2$ in the same plane, and then it is obvious that there is a tangent line. More generally, whenever you can find a regular parametrisation of a curve in the plane, you will also be able to find the tangent line.

Comment: Yes, "tangent line" would be more appropriate because my examples are from $\mathbb R^1$. By parametrisation might be the answer.